# Laravel Push method generate 0 id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I have user table that holds information about user. When I submit form for user, first I fill user object with information than later in the code on user object push() method is called but instead of generating proper id it generates 0 id in mysql database.

I really have no clue if this is something related to laravel or mysql.

Comment: Verify that id in that table is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I am using migration with $table->increments('id') on users table

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: You are right for some reason laravel 4.2 didn't turn on auto increment option. I know my form is right because its working on staging area but not so much on localhost where I am using migrations.

Comment: This is the code that I am using to create table. Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');  });

Comment: I mean the code in the controller or where is the code which makes you problem. Also this code better to put in comment and format as code. When you put code in the comments it is difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry for such late reply but your first comment did the job. For some reason Laravel increments didn't work as intended so I have to manually add this property into database.

Comment: No problem. Can you that accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that id in that table has AUTO_INCREMENT.